# Can we explain this strange JS behavior?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have tried the following in my console

```
var someVar1 = 1;
someVar1;            // 1
someVar1 in window;  // true

var someVar2 = 2;
someVar2 in this;    // true
someVar2 in window;  // true

delete someVar1;
someVar1;            // 1
someVar1 in window;  // true

this === window;     // true

var someVar3 = 3;
someVar3 in window;  // false
someVar3;            // 3
someVar3 in window;  // false
```

Why is `someVar3 in window` evaluating to `false`?

Test performed on Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 browser.

Comment: Instead of an image you should post an executable code snippet.......

Comment: I lost you at `someVar1 in window;`, this should be `"someVar1" in window`, otherwise it will be immediately `false`, at least on my chrome. I assume that you set `window[1]` and `window[2]` to something, before executing the shown code - without showing it here.

Comment: In my opinion, [**this is a great source**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) to at least start your journey from.

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

You are expecting `someVar3 in window` to return `true`. You are not getting `true` because you're using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator with `someVar3`'s value (i.e. `3`) and not its identifier `"someVar3"`.

Your code example boils down to:

```js
var someVar1 = 1;
var someVar3 = 3;

console.log(someVar1 in window);
console.log(someVar3 in window);
```

You actually checking if `1 is in window` and if `3 is in window`. And `window[1]` returns `window` whereas `window[3]` is `undefined` (try it in your console).

---

### Safe existence check

To check if the variable is declared and defined you can do the following:

```
window.someVar1
```

Or if you are inside a scope you can use:

```
typeof someVar1 !== "undefined"
```

---

### More about why `window[1]` returns a `Window`

> `window[0]`, `window[1]`, etc... Returns a reference to the `Window` object in the frames. See [`Window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) for more details.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)